# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function link()

Tags: php

Recentemente eu importei os arquivos de meu site para a máquina que estou utilizando atualmente e configurei os arquivos `config.php` e `admin/config.php` e outros (utilizo **XAMPP**).

Porém, quando tento acessar o site ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function link() on null in 
 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\admin\controller\error\not_found.php:16 
Stack trace: 
 #0 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\system\storage\modification\system\engine\action.php(51): 
    ControllerErrorNotFound->index() 
 #1 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\system\engine\front.php(59): 
    Action->execute(Object(Registry)) 
 #2 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\system\engine\front.php(52): 
    Front->execute(Object(Action)) 
 #3 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\system\framework.php(214): 
    Front->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) 
 #4 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\system\startup.php(124): 
    require_once('C:\\xampp1\\htdoc...') 
 #5 C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\index.php(24): 
    start('catalog') 
 #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp1\htdocs\shop1\admin\controller\error\not_found.php on line 16
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor? Preciso resolver este problema o quanto antes.

Comment: Confirme se os arquivos de configuração estão com a devida permissão. Dê uma olhada neste forum: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=203784